# How to output result to shell?

Tags: macos, prolog, swi-prolog, prologscript

I have a shell script, script.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
FIRST_ARGUMENT="$1"

swipl -s script4.pl $FIRST_ARGUMENT
```

prolog.pl:

```
:- initialization main.

query :-
        current_prolog_flag(argv, Argv),
        concat_atom(Argv, ' ', Atom),
        read_term_from_atom(Atom, Term, []),
        call(Term).

main :-
        catch(query, E, (print_message(error, E), fail)),
        halt.
main :-
        halt(1).

b(a).
a(c, d) :- writeln('I was called!').
```

Now if I call the script from the command line:

```
sh s.sh 'a(c,d).'
```

Will output `"I was called!"`.

But if I run a query except a yes/no answer:

```
sh s.sh 'b(a).'
```

All it tells me is:  `script4.pl compiled 0.00 sec, 7 clauses`.  When what I want is "true" because a fact was found that matches the input.  How can I get a result?

I want to query my Prolog program from Rake (a Ruby derivative).  I imagine a script is an easy way to do this, but maybe it's not powerful enough?

Comment: You need to decide if you really need to call your program as a script, instead of using the top level (the interpreter). There is almost no reason to use a script instead of the top level, except for maybe batch text processing (?).

Comment: @Boris I updated the question.  Maybe there's something I can do to make this better.

Comment: You can silence the informative message on the time taken to compile the file and the number of clauses in it by using the SWI-Prolog command line option `--quiet` or `-q`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple, admittedly crude, way is to add `writeln(true)` and `writeln(false)` to each of the success and fail clauses of `main/0`, respectively:

```
main :- catch(query, E, (print_message(error, E), fail)),
        writeln(true),
        halt.
main :- writeln(false),
        halt(1).
```

Though I'm sure there's a better solution to be had...

Comment: While I'L'I's method is a lot of fun, I used this method because it works on windows and mac.  I need both.

Comment: This method does seem more general, in the limited sense that it leaves it to the Prolog code to decide what sort of output to generate. Conversely, I'L'I's method seems to provide a certain guarantee on the unix side of things, assuring certain outputs from the shell script. The import point, i think, is that the output 'true.' and 'false.' only have a definite sense for Prolog at the top level. When we use Prolog programs as executables linked to other programs, we just want them to output whatever sort of data we need. Using Prolog to verify facts is a very special case of this.

Comment: @aBathologist, Well said — The method in my answer was something I came up with on a whim. While it is *fun* as P.Brian.Mackey put it, I think using a solution that has prolog deal with itself should be preferred. It's nice to see this kind of thinking with everyone's answers, since it does allow one to go outside the realm of what might have been done before.

Comment: @l'L'l Agreed! Seeing a variety of approaches different solutions is really helpful and refreshing. Gives me a better sense for the flexibility of these tools.

Answer (score 2):

Since the output of what you want prolog to produce is usually done strictly within it's interactive shell this is one of those things that requires some type of `crude` implementation. This particular one might be considered on the extreme end, ***but it does work***.

```
#!/bin/bash
FIRST_ARGUMENT="$1"

swipl -l script4.pl $FIRST_ARGUMENT',halt(n).' 2>&1 | sed 's/ERROR: halt\/1.*/True/g'
```

Result:

```
$ sh s.sh 'b(a)'
True
```

Of course you can come up with your own out-of-the-box method, which I encourage.

Comment: Anyone trying this be careful to pay close attention to this answer.  Notice that the argument `b(a)` does NOT have '.' because that's part of the shell command now.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, shell scripts returns zero on success and an integer other than zero, interpreted as an error code, on failure. So, you can use the standard `halt/1` predicate to return either zero or e.g. one depending on your query, respectively, succeeding or failing. You're already doing it, but you can make it a bit more clear with something like:

```
main :-
    (   query ->
        halt(0)
    ;   halt(1)
    ).
```

If the query may throw an exception, wrap it using the standard `catch/3` predicate:

```
main :-
    (   catch(query, _, fail) ->
        halt(0)
    ;   halt(1)
    ).
```

You can also use the exception to choose the exit value:

```
main :-
    (   catch(query, Error, error_handler(Error)) ->
        halt(0)
    ;   halt(1)
    ).

error_handler(error1) :- halt(2).
error_handler(error2) :- halt(3).
...
```

In this case, zero would mean success, one would mean failure, and any other integer would mean the corresponding error.